# How to keep session state variables across a multipage app in Streamlit

Tags: python, streamlit

My app has a few pages, and the first time it loads, it will detect if there is an access token in the session state, if not the user with click on the login to go to Azure Id, and then a code will be returned in the query parameters and then an access token will be retrieved, thenI can use to render some buttons depending on the user groups, etc.

This works perfectly fine on my homepage.

Security.py

```
# Initialize the MSAL ConfidentialClientApplication
app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(CLIENT_ID, authority=AUTHORITY, client_credential=CLIENT_SECRET)


# Function to get the authorization URL
def get_auth_url():
    """
    Generate the authorization URL for user sign-in.
    """
    auth_url = app.get_authorization_request_url(SCOPE, redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI)
    return auth_url


# Function to exchange authorization code for an access token
def get_token_from_code(auth_code):
    """
    Exchange an authorization code for an access token.
    """
    result = app.acquire_token_by_authorization_code(auth_code, scopes=SCOPE, redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI)
    return result['access_token']


# Function to get user information
def get_user_info(access_token):
    """
    Get user information using the provided access token.
    """
    headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'}
    response = requests.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', headers=headers)
    return response.json()


# Function to get user's groups with display names
def get_user_groups(access_token):
    """
    Get the user's groups with display names using the provided access token.
    """
    headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'}
    params = {
        '$select': 'displayName, id',  # Specify the fields you want to retrieve
    }
    response = requests.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf', headers=headers, params=params)
    return response.json()


# Function to handle the OAuth2 redirect flow
def handle_redirect():
    """
    Handle the OAuth2 redirect flow, retrieve the access token, and store it in the session.
    """
    if not st.session_state.get('access_token'):
        code = st.experimental_get_query_params().get('code')
        if code:
            access_token = get_token_from_code(code)
            st.session_state['access_token'] = access_token
            st.experimental_set_query_params()
```

then utils.py have this:

def setup_page():
if st.experimental_get_query_params().get('code'):
# Handle the OAuth2 redirect if an authorization code is present
handle_redirect()
access_token = st.session_state.get('access_token')

```
if access_token:
    # If an access token is available, retrieve and display user information and groups
    user_info = get_user_info(access_token)
    st.session_state['user_info'] = user_info
    # Get user's group information
    user_groups = get_user_groups(access_token)
    st.session_state['user_groups'] = user_groups

    # Display user's group information, handling cases where 'displayName' is not available
    # if 'value' in user_groups:
    # for group in user_groups['value']:
    # group_display_name = group.get('displayName', group.get('mailNickname', group["id"]))
    # group_id = group["id"]
    # st.write(group_id)

    # return True
else:
    # If there's no access token, prompt the user to sign in
    st.write("Please sign-in to use this app.")
    auth_url = get_auth_url()
    st.markdown(f"<a href='{auth_url}' target='_self'>Sign In</a>", unsafe_allow_html=True)
    st.stop()
```

and then on both my homepage and page1.py, page2.py I just call setup_page.

However when I to from homepage to page1, session_state is lost, the access token is not there anymore.

Whats causing this?

Comment: Where do you deploy your app?

Comment: azure web app...

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74968179/session-state-is-reset-in-streamlit-multipage-app?rq=2

Comment: that didnt work

Answer (score 2):

Streamlit's **session_state** is designed to maintain session-specific state across reruns of a script. However, it is not designed to persist across different pages or app instances. When you navigate from one page to another in Streamlit, each page is essentially a separate instance of the script.

In your case, when you move from the homepage to page1, the script for page1 is re-executed, and the **session_state** is reset. To maintain state across different pages, you can consider using other methods, such as passing parameters through the URL, storing information in a database, or using a global variable.

Here's a high-level suggestion:

1. **Pass Access Token through URL Parameters:**

When you redirect the user to page1, append the access token as a parameter in the URL.
In page1, read the URL parameters and use the access token.

**Example:**

```
# Redirect from homepage
page1_url = f"/page1?access_token={access_token}"
st.markdown(f"<a href='{page1_url}'>Go to Page 1</a>", unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

```
# In page1.py
access_token = st.experimental_get_query_params().get('access_token')
```

2. **Store Access Token in a Database or External Storage:**

Store the access token in a database or an external storage (considering security implications).
Retrieve the access token in each page based on the user's session.

**Example:**

```
# Store access token
st.session_state['access_token'] = access_token
# Retrieve access token in page1
access_token = st.session_state.get('access_token')
```

Choose the approach that fits your application's requirements and security considerations. Be cautious about security when passing sensitive information in URLs or storing it in external storage.

Happy Learning!!!